# Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, flexbox

I want to have a vertical menu with a specific height.

Each child must fill the height of the parent and have middle-aligned text.

The number of children is random, so I have to work with dynamic values.

Div `.container` contains a random number of children (`.item`) that always have to fill the height of the parent. To achieve that I used flexbox.

For making links with text aligned to the middle I am using `display: table-cell` technique. But using table displays requires using a height 100%.

My problem is that `.item-inner { height: 100% }` is not working in webkit (Chrome).

1. Is there a fix for this problem?
2. Or is there a different technique to make all `.item` fill the height of the parent with text vertical aligned to middle?

[Example here jsFiddle, should be viewed in Firefox and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/y8mboo2s/)

```css
.container {
  height: 20em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid black
}
.item {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
.item-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
a {
  background: orange;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it has now been fixed - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898

Comment: This isn't specifically relevant to OP, but might be relevant for googlers who land here for "safari display absolute height 100% doesnt work" or something similar. I have an element like this inside a flex container and had to specify `top:0` and `left:0` to have it appear as expected.

Comment: @vsync hasn't been fixed yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226298/why-cant-this-textarea-assume-the-full-height-of-its-parent-in-chrome/

Answer (score 509, accepted):

### Solution

Use nested flex containers.

Get rid of percentage heights. Get rid of table properties. Get rid of `vertical-align`. Avoid absolute positioning. *Just stick with flexbox all the way through.*

Apply `display: flex` to the flex item (`.item`), making it a flex container. This automatically sets `align-items: stretch`, which tells the child (`.item-inner`) to expand the full height of the parent.

*Important: Remove specified heights from flex items for this method to work.* If a child has a height specified (e.g. `height: 100%`), then it will ignore the `align-items: stretch` coming from the parent. For the `stretch` default to work, the child's height must compute to `auto` [(full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878379/3597276)).

Try this (no changes to HTML):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 20em;
    border: 5px solid black
}

.item {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.item-inner {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;                            /* new */

    /* height: 100%;                    <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* width: 100%;                     <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* display: table;                  <-- remove; unnecessary */  
}

a {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;                            /* new */
    align-items: center;                /* new; vertically center text */
    background: orange;

    /* display: table-cell;             <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* vertical-align: middle;          <-- remove; unnecessary */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8mboo2s/3/)

---

### Explanation

> My problem is that `.item-inner { height: 100% }` is not working in
>   webkit (Chrome).

It's not working because you're using percentage height in a way that doesn't conform with the traditional implementation of the spec.

> [**10.5 Content height: the `height` property**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property)
>
> **percentage**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to `auto`.
>
> **auto**
>  The height depends on the values of other properties.

In other words, for percentage height to work on an in-flow child, the parent *must* have a set height.

In your code, the top-level container has a defined height: `.container { height: 20em; }`

The third-level container has a defined height: `.item-inner { height: 100%; }`

But between them, the second-level container – `.item` – *does not* have a defined height. Webkit sees that as a missing link.

`.item-inner` is telling Chrome: *give me `height: 100%`*. Chrome looks to the parent (`.item`) for reference and responds: *100% of what? I don't see anything* (ignoring the `flex: 1` rule that is there). As a result, it applies `height: auto` (content height), in accordance with the spec.

Firefox, on the other hand, now accepts a parent's flex height as a reference for the child's percentage height. IE11 and Edge accept flex heights, as well.

Also, Chrome will accept `flex-grow` as an adequate parent reference *if used in conjunction with `flex-basis`* (any numerical value works ([`auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53870751/3597276) won't), including `flex-basis: 0`). As of this writing, however, this solution fails in Safari.

```css
#outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      INNER
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Four Solutions

***1. Specify a height on all parent elements***

A reliable cross-browser solution is to specify a height on all parent elements. This prevents missing links, which Webkit-based browsers consider a violation of the spec.

*Note that `min-height` and `max-height` are not acceptable. It must be the `height` property.*

More details here:  [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

***2. CSS Relative & Absolute Positioning***

Apply `position: relative` to the parent and `position: absolute` to the child.

Size the child with `height: 100%` and `width: 100%`, or use the offset properties: `top: 0`, `right: 0`, `bottom: 0`, `left: 0`.

With absolute positioning, percentage height works without a specified height on the parent.

***3. Remove unnecessary HTML containers (recommended)***

Is there a need for two containers around `button`? Why not remove `.item` or `.item-inner`, or both? Although [`button` elements sometimes fail as flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35464067/3597276), they can be flex items. Consider making `button` a child of `.container` or `.item`, and removing gratuitous mark-up.

Here's an example:

```css
.container {
    height: 20em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 5px solid black
}

a {
    flex: 1;
    background: orange;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    display: flex;                   /* nested flex container (for aligning text) */
    align-items: center;             /* center text vertically */
    justify-content: center;         /* center text horizontally */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a>Button</a>
    <a>Button</a>
    <a>Button</a>
</div>
```

***4. Nested Flex Containers (recommended)***

Get rid of percentage heights. Get rid of table properties. Get rid of `vertical-align`. Avoid absolute positioning. *Just stick with flexbox all the way through.*

Apply `display: flex` to the flex item (`.item`), making it a flex container. This automatically sets `align-items: stretch`, which tells the child (`.item-inner`) to expand the full height of the parent.

*Important: Remove specified heights from flex items for this method to work.* If a child has a height specified (e.g. `height: 100%`), then it will ignore the `align-items: stretch` coming from the parent. For the `stretch` default to work, the child's height must compute to `auto` [(full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44878379/3597276)).

Try this (no changes to HTML):

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 20em;
    border: 5px solid black
}

.item {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.item-inner {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;                            /* new */

    /* height: 100%;                    <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* width: 100%;                     <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* display: table;                  <-- remove; unnecessary */  
}

a {
    display: flex;                      /* new; nested flex container */
    flex: 1;                            /* new */
    align-items: center;                /* new; vertically center text */
    background: orange;

    /* display: table-cell;             <-- remove; unnecessary */
    /* vertical-align: middle;          <-- remove; unnecessary */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <a>Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8mboo2s/3/)

Comment: I fixed my issue using height:auto

Comment: just some remark taken from the explanation link of this great post - "align-items: stretch" makes flex children to expand across the cross axis of the container - that is to stretch children to the height, the flex container should have flex-direction as row.

Comment: I can confirm that using nested flex containers works best. We used flexbox inconsistently in our menu. Instead of using flex: 1 and display: flex on parent containers we used height: 100% at some places. Everything worked as expected after we replaced the corresponding definitions. Thanks @Michael_B for the hint! :)

Comment: @JamesHarrington, CSS has grown over time and is *complex* ;-)

Comment: Each solution should be a different answer. How can I vote in a specific solution this way?

Comment: Thank you so much for the "remove height" recommendation as that was the problem I have been spending the past hour trying to solve!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/49c1kzxv/

Hi, I just have a little edit :D change background from white to black. Can you see the white space next to the border? How can I remove it?

Comment: Add `body { margin: 0 }`. Will override the default margin on the `body` element. http://jsfiddle.net/ks6aztqr/  @vnoo

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin It does not fix my issue :D Can you please check my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134840/chrome-safari-not-filling-100-height-width-of-flex-parent

Comment: I swear, you're a complete life saver. I never looked at it that way **"Get rid of everything and use flexbox all the way through"** made my styles more consistent across anything

Comment: **This** (not this answer but flexbox) **is a messed up implementation. Flexbox should be used for the elements it's specified for and not mess up everything down the line, or down the parenting structure, one should say.** But thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 40):

Specifying a flex attribute to the container worked for me:

```
.container {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

This ensures the height is set and doesn't grow either.

Comment: I had so wanted this to work, but I end up with the container off the bottom of the viewport

Answer (score 16):

Solution: Remove `height: 100%` in *.item-inner* and add `display: flex` in *.item*

Demo: https://codepen.io/tronghiep92/pen/NvzVoo

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Do flex children automatically take  stretch to the height of their container? Is this why this works?

Comment: @ReeceKenney, yes, to your questions. This is explained in my answer. See solution #4.

Answer (score 11):

For Mobile Safari There is a Browser fix. you need to add **-webkit-box** for iOS devices.

Ex.

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
align-items: stretch;
```

if you're using `align-items: stretch;` property for parent element,  remove the `height : 100%` from the child element.

Comment: omg thank you so much you saved me from so much headache! `display: -webkit-box;` is exactly what I needed. It turns out even in late 2020, iOS devices _still_ don't have predictable flex support

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue in iOS 8, 9 and 10 and the info above couldn't fix it, however I did discover a solution after a day of working on this. Granted it won't work for everyone but in my case my items were stacked in a column and had 0 height when it should have been content height. Switching the css to be row and wrap fixed the issue. This only works if you have a single item and they are stacked but since it took me a day to find this out I thought I should share my fix!

```
.wrapper {
    flex-direction: column; // <-- Remove this line
    flex-direction: row; // <-- replace it with
    flex-wrap: wrap; // <-- Add wrapping
}

.item {
    width: 100%;
}
```